# show the names of the columns of different tables in the same order than these appeared in every table in sql

Tags: sql-server, database, sys

I need to bring a  technical report describing all the table with its columns that belongs to a certain database. The thing is, it was required to bring the - let´s call it - descripcion of the tables in this database respecting the order of the columns inside the table.

For example, if I have the table_1 that has the columns Column_D,Column_A,Column_M,Column_E in that particular order, I should bring the report just like this

> Table     -     column
>
> Table_1        Column_D
>
> Table_1        Column_A
>
> Table_1        Column_M
>
> Table_1        Column_E

And so on with All the table in the database.

I am using this query

```
select t.name, c.name
from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t
on c.object_id = t.object_id
```

The problem is that I am getting the information that I want,  only that organized by the column field.

> Table     -     column
>
> Table_1        Column_A
>
> Table_1        Column_D
>
> Table_1        Column_E
>
> Table_1        Column_M

But if I add a where clause to the query

```
select t.name, c.name
from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t
on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.object_id = 123
```

I will have the result that I want but only for that particular table.

Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Without an order by clause, you are leaving the ordering up to SQL to determine based on optimised query execution. You probably want:

```
select t.name, c.name
from sys.columns c 
inner join sys.tables t
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
order by t.name, c.column_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the DBName with your database name in the below query

```
select Table_Name, Column_Name
from  DbName.information_schema.columns c 
order by table_name, ordinal_position
```